# Show swatches in yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with multiple axes. The same axis can be used for multiple curves.
I would like to draw colored swatches next to the y axes to make it easier to identify which curve belongs to which axis.
I don't find any API setting or sample. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: See [this plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/23/highcharts-legend-yaxis).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. You can write this as an answer. I will mark it as solved. Thanks